# Keeping selection at the bottom of EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

My app puts some text into an `EditText`. The text is ca. 3 times longer than the visible area of the `EditText`. The app then selects a piece of text (usually a sentence) via `EditText.setSelection(int start, int stop)`.

The problem is that the selection is always placed at different parts of the visible area: top, middle, bottom. However there is enough text and short sentences there so that the selection can be kept at the bottom.

Is there a way to force the `EditText` to keep the selection at the bottom of its visible area?

To illustrate:

```
Text piece 1.
Text piece 2.
Text piece 3.
Text piece 4.
Text piece 5.
--- Visible area ---
|Text piece 6.     |
|Text piece 7.     |
|Text piece 8.     |
|Text piece 9.     | Text pieces 9 and 10 are selected,
|Text piece 10.    | thus at the bottom
--------------------
Text piece 11. 
Text piece 12. 
Text piece 13. 
Text piece 14. 
Text piece 15.
```

Comment: so you have like a long paragraph text in edit text and whichever selection you give programmatically you want that line to be placed as last visible line on edittext, did i understood correctly ?

Comment: @Sahil Yes. But the selection can also be spread over multiple lines. For example, if the visible area is 10 lines and the selection is 2 lines, then the selection should be placed at lines 9 and 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to put such text into the `EditText` that the part that will be later selected is at the very end of it. In such a case the selection will be guaranteed at the bottom of the visible area.

As the part of text that follows the selection isn't visible anyway it doesn't make sense to include it in the text.

At least in my scenario it is acceptable.